# Text output of the executable is partially seen on console

Tags: c, loops, printing, console, dev-c++

I've written a simple C program that prints the output of several calculations as can be seen below. The problem is, I cannot see the output with expected values, it seems output can only be seen partially and I don't know why. The code is valid, no compilation/build error occurs. I am not sure if this is specific to compiler (I use *Dev C++*) or it is compiler agnostic ?

When I run the code for small 'n' such as 17,29,103 exc. the the result displays correctly but after a while it starts not to print the first couple of elements.

For n=171 it does not show the first 24 elements.

My code is as below;

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int mod_exponent(int g,int m, int n);

int main(){
    int g,m,n,m1,i,t;
    g=2; n=171;

    for (m=0;m<=n;m++){
        t=mod_exponent(g,m,n);

        if(t!=-1)
            printf("%d^%d=%d mod %d\n \n", g,m,t,n) ;
    }

    return 0;  
}

int mod_exponent(int g,int m, int n){
    int s,r,m1,i,j,k,q,d[100];

    if (g<=0||m<0||n<=0){
        printf("wrong parameters\n") ;
        return -1;
    }

    m1=m;i=0;
    while(m1>=2){
        q=m1/2;
        d[i]=m1-q*2;
        m1=q; 
        i=i+1;
    }

    d[i]=m1; k=i;
    if(d[0]==1)
        r=g;

    if(d[0]==0) 
        r=1;

    s=g;
    for(i=1;i<k;i++)
        s=s*s %n;

    if(d[i]==1){
        r=r*s%n;
    }
    return r;
}
```

output  should look like this :2^0=1 mod 171, 2^1=2 mod 171,...2^171=167

but it starts from 24 and it looks like : 2^24=85 mod 171, 2^25=170 mod171 171,...2^171=167

Comment: This question is unreadable! Please spend some minimal effort in order to (by the least) indent your code appropriately. Also, please note that this is not a 'debug my code for free' service, and that you're expected to show what effort you've made in attempting to investigate the problem at hand on your own (that is, if you're expecting others to make an effort for you).

Comment: Have you tried using your debugger to step through and pinpoint where your code is going wrong? If not and you're not too familiar with your debugger, check [this](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) out ( by Eric Lippert ). And also please try to format your code, as well as trying to give slightly more meaningful names to variables.

Comment: @barakmanos is right, you must pay attention on asking a legitimate question, code must be easily readable so that users can easily help you. Anyways, your code is working fine and the problem is based on output buffer exceed. I've answered your question down below, be more specific and pay more attention on your next questions. You are welcome to the StackOverflow community :)

Comment: if the output in the answer is correct this seems pretty fishy, `2^2=2 mod 171` `2^3=4 mod 171` `2^4=4 mod 171` or should `^`mean something different than power to

Comment: Kami Kaze code is fine. Actually it is repeated squaring algorithm. The problem was the output had been seen only partially on the console. It seems that, it was  because of  the program  exceeded the console buffer. now solved. It worked fine when I send to the output to a file.

Answer (score 1):

#### A - Explanation

Your code is actually working, the problem is the output of the program just exceeds the buffer of the console output. So, as a simple solution, you should write your output of your program into a text file. If you are using windows, open a **command line window** and simply pass the output to a file (with `>>` operator) and check the output via the file with a file editor (*notepad, notepad++ vs.*) as below;

Assuming your compiled executable filename is **so.exe**;

```
C:\Users\Levent\Desktop\so>so >> output.txt

C:\Users\Levent\Desktop\so>output.txt
```

#### B - Steps

1. Open a command line window by pressing `window key + r` and write `cmd`, press enter.

[image]

2. Change directory to your binary folder
3. Run your executable binary file with *file.exe >> output.txt*
4. Open your file with arbitrary text editor (like notepad ?)

#### C - Example on Windows CMD

[image]

#### D - Output

The output of your code is as below;

```
2^0=1 mod 171

2^1=2 mod 171

2^2=2 mod 171

2^3=4 mod 171

2^4=4 mod 171

2^5=8 mod 171

2^6=4 mod 171

2^7=8 mod 171

2^8=16 mod 171

2^9=32 mod 171

2^10=16 mod 171

2^11=32 mod 171

2^12=16 mod 171

2^13=32 mod 171

2^14=16 mod 171

2^15=32 mod 171

2^16=85 mod 171

2^17=170 mod 171

2^18=85 mod 171

2^19=170 mod 171

2^20=85 mod 171

2^21=170 mod 171

2^22=85 mod 171

2^23=170 mod 171

2^24=85 mod 171

2^25=170 mod 171

2^26=85 mod 171

2^27=170 mod 171

2^28=85 mod 171

2^29=170 mod 171

2^30=85 mod 171

2^31=170 mod 171

2^32=43 mod 171

2^33=86 mod 171

2^34=43 mod 171

2^35=86 mod 171

2^36=43 mod 171

2^37=86 mod 171

2^38=43 mod 171

2^39=86 mod 171

2^40=43 mod 171

2^41=86 mod 171

2^42=43 mod 171

2^43=86 mod 171

2^44=43 mod 171

2^45=86 mod 171

2^46=43 mod 171

2^47=86 mod 171

2^48=43 mod 171

2^49=86 mod 171

2^50=43 mod 171

2^51=86 mod 171

2^52=43 mod 171

2^53=86 mod 171

2^54=43 mod 171

2^55=86 mod 171

2^56=43 mod 171

2^57=86 mod 171

2^58=43 mod 171

2^59=86 mod 171

2^60=43 mod 171

2^61=86 mod 171

2^62=43 mod 171

2^63=86 mod 171

2^64=139 mod 171

2^65=107 mod 171

2^66=139 mod 171

2^67=107 mod 171

2^68=139 mod 171

2^69=107 mod 171

2^70=139 mod 171

2^71=107 mod 171

2^72=139 mod 171

2^73=107 mod 171

2^74=139 mod 171

2^75=107 mod 171

2^76=139 mod 171

2^77=107 mod 171

2^78=139 mod 171

2^79=107 mod 171

2^80=139 mod 171

2^81=107 mod 171

2^82=139 mod 171

2^83=107 mod 171

2^84=139 mod 171

2^85=107 mod 171

2^86=139 mod 171

2^87=107 mod 171

2^88=139 mod 171

2^89=107 mod 171

2^90=139 mod 171

2^91=107 mod 171

2^92=139 mod 171

2^93=107 mod 171

2^94=139 mod 171

2^95=107 mod 171

2^96=139 mod 171

2^97=107 mod 171

2^98=139 mod 171

2^99=107 mod 171

2^100=139 mod 171

2^101=107 mod 171

2^102=139 mod 171

2^103=107 mod 171

2^104=139 mod 171

2^105=107 mod 171

2^106=139 mod 171

2^107=107 mod 171

2^108=139 mod 171

2^109=107 mod 171

2^110=139 mod 171

2^111=107 mod 171

2^112=139 mod 171

2^113=107 mod 171

2^114=139 mod 171

2^115=107 mod 171

2^116=139 mod 171

2^117=107 mod 171

2^118=139 mod 171

2^119=107 mod 171

2^120=139 mod 171

2^121=107 mod 171

2^122=139 mod 171

2^123=107 mod 171

2^124=139 mod 171

2^125=107 mod 171

2^126=139 mod 171

2^127=107 mod 171

2^128=169 mod 171

2^129=167 mod 171

2^130=169 mod 171

2^131=167 mod 171

2^132=169 mod 171

2^133=167 mod 171

2^134=169 mod 171

2^135=167 mod 171

2^136=169 mod 171

2^137=167 mod 171

2^138=169 mod 171

2^139=167 mod 171

2^140=169 mod 171

2^141=167 mod 171

2^142=169 mod 171

2^143=167 mod 171

2^144=169 mod 171

2^145=167 mod 171

2^146=169 mod 171

2^147=167 mod 171

2^148=169 mod 171

2^149=167 mod 171

2^150=169 mod 171

2^151=167 mod 171

2^152=169 mod 171

2^153=167 mod 171

2^154=169 mod 171

2^155=167 mod 171

2^156=169 mod 171

2^157=167 mod 171

2^158=169 mod 171

2^159=167 mod 171

2^160=169 mod 171

2^161=167 mod 171

2^162=169 mod 171

2^163=167 mod 171

2^164=169 mod 171

2^165=167 mod 171

2^166=169 mod 171

2^167=167 mod 171

2^168=169 mod 171

2^169=167 mod 171

2^170=169 mod 171

2^171=167 mod 171
```